# Use another file A if file B does not exist

Tags: python, file, if-statement

I think it is a simple task. I tried a lot of things with no success.

I want to use a file A on a network directory and when I'm offline I want to use file B on my ssd.

```
file_PATH = "y:/file_A.txt"

if os.path.isfile(file_PATH):
    file_to_use = "y:/file_A.txt"
else:
    file_to_use = "d:/file_B.txt"
```

It doesn't work with this piece of code.
When I rename file_A for testing, file_B will not be used.

**UPDATE**

I've found the (very silly) mistake. It was a misspelling of one of the two directories.

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: Are you referencing file_PATH or file_to_use?

Comment: I'm referencing file_to_use. file_PATH is for checking if the file exists. I've edited my question.

Comment: Are you using exactly those filenames or maybe `"y:\file_A.txt"`?  The `\f` will be interpreted as a form-feed.

Comment: @cdarke. I use other filenames. The filenames in my question are for demonstration purposes.

Comment: OK, do you have back-slashes in their names?

Comment: No, only underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) and also think about using [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for building your path.

```python
file_PATH = "y:/file_A.txt"

if os.path.exists(file_PATH):
    file_to_use = "y:/file_A.txt"
else:
    file_to_use = "d:/file_B.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pathlib

file_PATH = pathlib.Path('y:/file_A.txt')

if file_PATH.is_file():
    file_to_use = "y:/file_A.txt"
else:
    file_to_use = "d:/file_B.txt"
```

EDIT: due to comment about Python 3.4

You can do it with [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) with Python 2:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> file_path = 'c:/file_false.txt'
>>> os.path.exists(file_path)
False
>>> file_path = 'c:/file_real.txt'
os.path.exists(file_path)
True
```

So

```
import os.path
file_PATH = 'y:/file_A.txt'

if os.path.exists(file_path):
    file_to_use = "y:/file_A.txt"
else:
    file_to_use = "d:/file_B.txt"
```

Comment: pathlib is a python 3.4 module. I do not have python 3.4. See my comment on Abhishake gupta answer.

Comment: You can use os.path.exists - if it doesn't work for you, then check that you are not escaping in the string - 'c:\file' should be written as 'c:\\file' - or just use unix forward slash style instead. c:/path/to/file

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check for the existence of the file.

In python 3.4 : the pathlib module offers an object-oriented approach-:

```
from pathlib import Path
if Path(r"/path/to/file_A.txt").is_file():
    file_to_use = "y:/file_A.txt"

elif Path(r"/path/to/file_B.txt").is_file():
    file_to_use = "d:/file_B.txt"
else:
    # Do something if both files don't exist
```

Comment: I'm not aible to use python 3.4, because of restrictions from our IT Service.